# My navigation bar is not aligning properly after adjusting the padding and margin

Tags: html, css

I am new to stack-overflow so hope I am posting this question right. I have attached a screenshot of my problem with the aligning.

I am trying to achieve for the writing in the nav bar to align properly so it is straight and doesn't look out of line if you understand what i am trying to say?

i have tried adjust the margin and the padding several times and still no luck so I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

Any suggestions would be great and will be very appreciated.

[Picture of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfn7Z.png)

```css
* {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

html {
 min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
 font-family: 'Staatliches', cursive;
 background-image: url(images/trees.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 1920px 700px;
}

img {
 float: left;
 padding-bottom: 7px;
}

span {
 padding: 20px;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
}

.nav {
 background-color: #100D0E;
 padding: 15px;
 text-align: right;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#matty {
 font-size: 18px;
 float: left;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 3px;
}

span:hover {
 border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;

}

label {
 color: #fff;
 margin: 0 40px 0 0;
 font-size: 30px;
 display: none;
}

#toggle {
 display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 723px) {
 label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 body {
  background-image: url(images/grey.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: 1920px 700px;
 }

 img {
  padding-top: 10px;
 }


 .nav {
  text-align: right;
 }

 #matty {
  padding-top: 13px;

 }

 .menu {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  
 }
 span:hover {
 display: block;

    }

 .menu a {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
 }

 #toggle:checked + .menu {
  display: block;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Basic | HTML | CSS</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Staatliches" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>


<div class="nav">
 <img src="images/legohead.png" width="25px" height="25px">
 <a id="matty" href="index.html">Matty</a>
  <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
  <div class="menu">
  <span><a href="#Services">Services</a></span>
  <span><a href="#Store">Store</a></span>
  <span><a href="#Work">Work</a></span>
  <span><a href="#Gallery">Gallery</a></span>
  <span><a href="#Team">Team</a></span>
  <span><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></span>
  <span><a href="#Pricing">Pricing</a></span>
 </div>
</div>









</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the text of the menu items to be to the left of the screen, remove text-align:right; from your nav class

If you use bootstrap, you can do something like the following:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand">Index Page</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming you want to vertically align your menu items to the center? I like to use flexbox, but not sure if that is what you need in this particular case. Anyway, you can add flexbox to the nav class like this.

```
.nav{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```